# ignore dependencies when setting CANCELED todo-state

Tags: org-mode, todo, dependency

**CONTEXT**

I have `org-todo-keywords` set to `"TODO(t) | DONE(d) CANCELED(c)"`.

Also, I have configured `org-todo-state-triggers` to

```
(cons 'quote (list (cons 'todo (list (cons org-archive-tag nil)))
             (cons "CANCELED" (list (cons org-archive-tag t)))))
```

This sets the `:ARCHIVE:` tag on the entire subtree, once the todo-state is set to `CANCELED`. It also automatically removes the tag if the todo-state is changed back to `TODO`.

**PROBLEM**

Finally, I have `org-enforce-todo-dependencies` set to `t`.

This would prevent setting the todo-state to `DONE`, when any subtask is not yet `DONE`.

Unfortunately, it has the undesirable side-effect, that until all subtasks are in done state (i.e. `DONE` or `CANCELED`), I would not be able to set the parent task to the **CANCELED** state, as it is blocked by the enforcement rule.

Is there a way to make the **CANCELED** todo-state ignore the subtask dependencies, or even better, to set the entire subtree to **CANCELED** state atomically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually explained in the [docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html) that it is possible to simply override the enforcement of todo dependencies by using the `C-c C-t` command with triple prefix argument: `C-u C-u C-u`.

Also, there is no need to set all the subtasks individually to `CANCELED` state, as the archive-tag archives the entire subtree, which removes all the subtasks from the agenda.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a builtin way to accomplish this "easily", so I wrote the following two functions which can manually be invoked to change the status of all `todo states` in a subtree to `CANCELLED` and back. You can use `undo` right after cancelling to reset it but this won't work some days later, therefore the uncancel-function.

**IMPORTANT:** This includes **ALL** `todo` keywords. If you created some other keywords like `HOLD` or `WAITING`, they will also be changed to `CANCELLED` and on "uncancelling" they will be set to `TODO`. `Done` keywords will remain as they are. (check the example)

One Logbook entry will automatically be created for the main headline if desired.

*You can change the `CANCELLED` to `CANCELED` in the first line (I didn't know both spellings are okay).*

```
;; Since there are different spellings for that word we rather have a variable for it
(setq org-cancel-keyword "CANCELLED")

;; Taken from http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#Projects
(defun bh/is-project-p ()
  "Any task with a todo keyword subtask"
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (let ((has-subtask)
          (subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t)))
          (is-a-task (member (nth 2 (org-heading-components)) org-todo-keywords-1)))
      (save-excursion
        (forward-line 1)
        (while (and (not has-subtask)
                    (< (point) subtree-end)
                    (re-search-forward "^\*+ " subtree-end t))
          (when (member (org-get-todo-state) org-todo-keywords-1)
            (setq has-subtask t))))
      (and is-a-task has-subtask))))

(defun my/org-cancel-subtree ()
  (interactive)
  (save-mark-and-excursion
      (let ((projects (list)))
        (org-map-entries
         (lambda ()
           (if (org-entry-is-todo-p)
                (if (bh/is-project-p)
                    (push (point) projects)
                  (org-todo org-cancel-keyword))))
         nil
         'tree)
        (dolist (project projects)
          (goto-char project)
          (org-todo org-cancel-keyword))))
    ;; We need to mark the main project as cancelled, too
    (if (org-entry-is-todo-p) (org-todo org-cancel-keyword)))

(defun my/org-uncancel-subtree ()
  (interactive)
  (save-mark-and-excursion
    ;; Ignore the first line, so that the note will be inserted on the first line
    (let ((first-header (save-excursion (org-back-to-heading)(point))))
      (org-map-entries
       (lambda () (if (not (= (point) first-header)) (org-todo "TODO")))
         (concat "/" org-cancel-keyword)
         'tree)))
    (org-todo "TODO"))
```

Here an example.
Before cancellation:

```
* TODO My Tree
** TODO Some todo
** TODO A Project with TODOs in it
*** TODO Some todo
*** DONE A DONE todo
*** TODO another project within a project
**** TODO some todo
**** HOLD This todo is on HOLD
:LOGBOOK:
- State "HOLD"       from              [2020-01-05 Sun 14:08] \\
  reason
:END:
**** TODO some more todo
**** Just an information - not a todo
** TODO more TODOs
** more Informations
** TODO Another TODO
```

After Cancellation:

```
* CANCELLED My Tree                                               :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
:LOGBOOK:
- State "CANCELLED"  from "TODO"       [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57] \\
  This is my cancellation Note.
:END:
** CANCELLED Some todo                                           :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
** CANCELLED A Project with TODOs in it                          :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
*** CANCELLED Some todo                                         :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
*** DONE A DONE todo
*** CANCELLED another project within a project                  :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
**** CANCELLED some todo                                       :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
**** CANCELLED This todo is on HOLD                            :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
:LOGBOOK:
- State "HOLD"       from              [2020-01-05 Sun 14:08] \\
  reason
:END:
**** CANCELLED some more todo                                  :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
**** Just an information - not a todo
** CANCELLED more TODOs                                          :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
** more Informations
** CANCELLED Another TODO                                        :CANCELLED:
CLOSED: [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57]
```

After "uncancellation":

```
* TODO My Tree
:LOGBOOK:
- State "TODO"       from "CANCELLED"  [2020-01-05 Sun 17:30]
- State "CANCELLED"  from "TODO"       [2020-01-05 Sun 15:57] \\
  This is my cancellation Note.
:END:
** TODO Some todo
** TODO A Project with TODOs in it
*** TODO Some todo
*** DONE A DONE todo
*** TODO another project within a project
**** TODO some todo
**** TODO This todo is on HOLD
:LOGBOOK:
- State "HOLD"       from              [2020-01-05 Sun 14:08] \\
  reason
:END:
**** TODO some more todo
**** Just an information - not a todo
** TODO more TODOs
** more Informations
** TODO Another TODO
```

> Funfact: It took me about 3 hours and some useless debugging to find out that `/` prefix matches TODOs

Comment: Please remove the vulgar language from your example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think my issue is less with the changing of the todo-state of the whole subtree, and more with overriding the dependency restrictions when changing to the CANCELED done state.

This is mainly because I already have a `org-todo-state-tags-triggers` rule for the CANCELED state, that it adds the `:ARCHIVED:` tag, and this way it archives the entire subtree outright. Also, it is easily reversible.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the solution to my problem.

For something what you are trying to do though, something like this might work better:

`(defun org-cancel-subtree ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (org-todo "CANCELED")
     (setq org-map-continue-from (outline-previous-heading)))
   "+TODO" 'tree))`

Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem, because the todo dependencies would still be enforced.